# Ubuntu User has Sudo/Root Access

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo

I have a user called Ubuntu which has root/sudo access after removing the user Ubuntu from group sudo.

```
sudo deluser ubuntu sudo
```

Groups Ubuntu user is currently in:

```
../html/ $ groups
ubuntu adm dialout cdrom floppy audio dip video plugdev netdev lxd
```

inside /etc/passwd

```
ubuntu:x:1000:1000:Ubuntu:/home/ubuntu:/bin/bash
```

using `sudo -l`

```
../html/ $ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for ubuntu:
    env_reset, mail_badpass, secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin\:/snap/bin

User ubuntu may run the following commands:
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
    (ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

I'm new to Linux administration and would like to know why this user is able to access sudo / root without using root password?

Comment: The 'ubuntu' account is necessary in cloud images and Ubuntu Base and containers and other copied (not installed) types of Ubuntu instances -- you need an account for the first login. Best practice is to use the 'ubuntu' account to set up your own secure, key-protected admin account, test your key access and your admin powers, then delete the 'ubuntu' account entirely.

Comment: You do understand that the Ubuntu system disallows `root` login. If you don't have a `sudo`-capable userid, you won't be able to manage your system.